# Get members of a private channel in Microsoft Teams

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, microsoft-graph, microsoft-teams

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://site-admin.sharepoint.com

$privateSites = Get-SPOSite | Where-Object -Property Template -eq "TEAMCHANNEL#0"
```

Any attempt to get the list of members for a private site returns with Access Denied.

Is there any way to do this in PowerShell?

Not familiar at all with graph API.

Comment: Did you try running this command with Global administrator or SharePoint tenant administrator roles?

Answer (score 0):

To get *Get members of a private channel in Microsoft Teams*, try running below command with administrative privileges:

```
Get-SPOUser -Site https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName | select * | Format-table -Wrap -AutoSize
```

**Documentation**: [Manage SharePoint Online users and groups with PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/manage-sharepoint-users-and-groups-with-powershell)

---

To get users from Group Site Collections in a tenant, use:

```
Get-SPOSite -Template GROUP#0 | ForEach {Get-SPOUser -Site $_.Url}
```

**Documentation**: [Get-SPOSite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/get-sposite)